# Describing android permissions in APK

Tags: android, apk

(Is there a way to | How do I) include a custom description for the base android permissions for my application?

For example, here's the default description of **Your location** permission as of Android 4.0.

```
coarse (network-based) location, fine (GPS) location
```

I want to change that to say

```
Ability to read your location is required by Feature X
```

Or something to that effect. Is this possible?

Comment: Nice Idea,AFAIK it's not Possible. But you can maximum do is add this as Description to your app on Site, cause also Market has its own terms to use for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. There's simply no way to define it in the Android Manifest beside declaring that your app wants permission X, Y or Z. That being said, I believe this is something a number of developers desire out of Android. **An alternative solution is to describe why you need the permissions in the Description section of your app when it reaches the Android Market.**

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because it is handled by Android to let the user to know what the App requires are going to use from device. The user should be noticed what the app is capable of,
Whether it can harm device or not.